# How to load more items without pages in API in Android recyclerview?

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to add a load more feature in my recyclerview. I followed some tips I found on Stackoverflow but each one requires the existence of pages in the API. In my API there are no pages and that's why I can't figure out how to adjust this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822115/how-to-handle-pagination-load-more-in-retrofit-2-0) to my recyclerview as there are no pages. Any answer would be appreciated!!